# REST to create a Sharepoint List in Node.js hosted offsite

Tags: rest, nodejs

I am trying to use request to create a SharePoint list with node. I am 90% sure all my headers are okay, but I am not too sure. I know all the auth headers are populated with values too; any help would be.

```
var inputJSON = {
    "Connection": {
        "SiteUrl": "na",
        "Tennent": "na",
        "Username": "na",
        "Password": "na"
    },
    "Request": {
        "Title": "Test List",
        "TemplateType": "100",
        "Description": "My test list description"
    }
};

var Toptions = {
    auth: {
        username: inputJSON.Connection.Username,
        password: inputJSON.Connection.Password
    },
    host: inputJSON.Connection.Tennent
};


var Sharepoint = require('sharepoint-auth');
Sharepoint(Toptions, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var requestOptions = {
            url: inputJSON.Connection.SiteUrl + '_api/web/lists',
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.List'
                },
                'AllowContentTypes': true,
                'BaseTemplate': 100,
                'ContentTypesEnabled': true,
                'Description': 'My list description',
                'Title': 'MY TEST LIST'
            },
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
                'Cookie': 'FedAuth=' + result.cookies.FedAuth + ';rtFa=' + result.cookies.rtFa + ';',
                'X-RequestDigest': result.requestDigest,
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + result.accessToken,
                'content-length': 255
            },
            json: true
        };

        var request = require('request');

        function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }

        }
        request(requestOptions, callback);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`sp-request`](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/sp-request) module for that purpose.
Your code will be:

```
var sprequest = require('sp-request');
var creds = {
    username: 'johndoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com',
    password: 'mycoolpass'
};
var request = sprequest.create(creds);
request.requestDigest('https://mysharepoint.com/sites/mysite')
    .then(function (digest) {
        return request.post('https://mysharepoint.com/sites/mysite' + '/_api/web/lists', {
            body: {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' },
                'AllowContentTypes': true,
                'BaseTemplate': 100,
                'ContentTypesEnabled': false,
                'Description': 'Test list',
                'Title': 'My List'
            },
            headers: {
                'X-RequestDigest': digest
            }
        });
    })
    .then(function () {
        console.log('list just created!!!');
    }, function (err) {
        if (err.message.indexOf('-2130575342') === -1) {
            console.log('Hmmmmm something went wrong');
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('list already exists!!!');
    })
        .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Hmmmmm something went wrong');
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Actually I'm the creator, so feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: Thanks! I should be able to use the whole API here right?

Comment: Right, you can use it

Comment: Hi @SergeiSergeev , I'm getting 400 Bad Request HTTPError on POST. What it could be ? It works fine with `sp-rest-proxy`. 

And list has been created I just want to add entry to existing one. I have also follow your doc from https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-request?activeTab=readme but same error